# javascript code to get multiple checked values from listbox php

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I have two dependent select box in my form for selecting country and state.

i have a multi select checkbox dropdown for selecting country,
 and i want to fetch state of selected country

but i cannot understand how to pass multiple checked id in my function from javascript.

**below is my html select list box code**

```
<?php
                                        echo $this->Form->input('UserLogDetail.service_area_category_id', array(
                                            'id' => 'shipping_type',
                                            'required' => false, 
                                            'multiple' =>'multiple',
                                            'type' => 'select',                                           
                                            'class' => 'form-control drop-arrow',
                                            'label' => false,
                                            'options' => $serviceCategory,
                                            'empty' => '--Select--'
                                        ));
                                        ?>

<?php
                                        echo $this->Form->input('UserLogDetail.skills', array(
                                            'class' => 'form-control',
                                            'required' => false,
                                            'id' => 'skill',
                                            'label' => false,
                                            'options' => '$states',
                                            'empty' => '--Select--'
                                        ));
                                        ?>
```

**javascript function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#shipping_type").on('change', function() {
            var id = $(this).val();           
            if (id) {
                 var dataString = 'id=' + id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Profiles", "action" => "loadSkills"),true); ?>',
                    data: dataString,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    cache: false,                  
                   success: function(html) {                       
                        $("#skill").html("");
                        $.each(html, function(key, value) {
                            $('<option>').val('').text('select');
                            $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#skill"));
                        });
                        $('#skill').selectpicker('refresh');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

**controlller function**

```
public function loadSkills() {
        $this->loadModel('Skill');
        $states = array();
        if (isset($this->request['data']['id'])) {
        $states = $this->Skill->find('list', array('fields' => array('Skill.id','Skill.skill_name'),'conditions' => array(
        'Skill.service_area_category_id IN' => explode(",",$this->request['data']['id']))));
        }         
        echo json_encode($states);
        exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to call ajax below way

javascript :

```
 $("#shipping_type").change(function() {

   $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Profiles", "action" => "loadSkills"),true); ?>',
                //passing data to php   
                data: { id:$(this).val()  },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                cache: false,                  
               success: function(html) {                       
                    $("#skill").html("");
                    $.each(html, function(key, value) {
                        $('<option>').val('').text('select');
                        $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#skill"));
                    });
                    $('#skill').selectpicker('refresh');
                }
            });
 });
```

php

```
 public function loadSkills() {
    $this->loadModel('Skill');
    $states = array();
      //Getting post id
    if (isset($this->request['id'])) {
    $states = $this->Skill->find('list', array('fields' => array('Skill.id','Skill.skill_name'),'conditions' => array(
    'Skill.service_area_category_id IN' => explode(",",$this->request['data']['id']))));
    }         
    echo json_encode($states);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: but on checkbox select event loadskills function is not calling from my ajax....i am using multiple checkbox select tag for selecting multiple country...plz see the below url for refrence .http://users.skavt.net/blaz/MultiSelect/demo.html

Comment: no this is not working...i saw in console but on checkbox click event no action is firing when i checked values inside my select tag..

Answer (score 0):

```
public function loadSkills() {
        $this->getServiceArea();
        $this->loadModel('Skill');
        $skills = array();
        if (isset($this->request['data']['id'])) {
        $ids = explode(",",$this->request['data']['id']);
        if(count($ids)>1){
            $skills = $this->Skill->find('list', array('fields' => array('Skill.id','Skill.skill_name'),'conditions' => array(
            'Skill.service_area_category_id IN' => $ids)));
            } else {
            $skills = $this->Skill->find('list', array('fields' => array('Skill.id','Skill.skill_name'),'conditions' => array(
        'Skill.service_area_category_id' => $ids)));
            }          
        }
        echo json_encode($skills);
        exit();
    }
```